# Is there a 'right' balance between php and javascript code, when building a site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is a 'right' balance when coding a web site between php code and javascript code.I mean how much and which parts of the code must be written on the server using php and which parts of the web site must be written on javascript so that they can be run locally on the web browser of the user and remove some of the workload out of server's shoulders?

Comment: no, it all depends ...

Comment: Just make sure you have a lot of both, and you'll be good!

Comment: There is even more to consider at the server-side: which part you should leave in php, and which pass to DBMS (MySQL etc).

Comment: and html and css and jpg and text and ....

Answer (score 2):

That is entirely based on information / knowledge only you know about.  Sit down and map out what things can be done on the client side, such as validation code.  Write down what things do I have to keep on the server side (database calls etc).  Only you can really determine this.

Just remember that the application you are about to write may be used by potential users, if they have to wait for simple things such as a radio button click (done on the server side) then they will be pretty disappointed.  Keep it simple and aim to keep validation, and minor click events on the client side.  Keep the server side to database calls (updates, etc).